# Show $\text{Gal}(K_\infty/\mathbb Q)\cong \mathbb Z_p^{\times}$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

Let $\zeta_{p^n}$ be the primitive $p^n$-th root of unity where $p$ is a prime and $K_n=\mathbb Q(\zeta_{p^n})$ the $p^n$-th cyclotomic field. Let $K_\infty=\bigcup K_n$.

Could someone give a proof of the isomorphism $\text{Gal}(K_\infty/\mathbb Q)\cong \mathbb Z_p^{\times}$?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: By $\Bbb Z_p^\times$ do you mean the finite group of size $p-1$?  Because the Galois group must be infinite, but that's just a finite group.

Comment: @GregoryGrant: No, $\mathbb{Z}_p$ means the $p$-adic integers (and in my opinion, should not be used to denote $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$). Pete: are you familiar with inverse limits?

Comment: Oh ok, that makes more sense then.  I agree there's a conflict of notation, but like it or not $\Bbb Z_p$ is used so often by so many people that it's probably a good idea to qualify it when using it for the $p$-adics.

Comment: Anyway, the $p$-adics are the inverse limit of the the groups $\Bbb Z/p^n\Bbb Z$ so this is not very surprising.

Comment: @RghtHndSd  Yes I am.

Comment: Does this page help? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_character

Comment: @RghtHndSd  My first thought was to consider how an arbitrary element $g$ of the galois group would act on $\zeta_{p^n}$. If $g(\zeta_{p^n})=\zeta_{p^n}^{a_g}$ then would $a_g$ be coprime to $p^n$?

Comment: @ Gregory Grant  I think it might help- many thanks.

Comment: Pete, that's a good start. Surely $g(\zeta_{p^n})=\zeta_{p^n}^{a_n}$. And, yes, $\gcd(a_n,p)=1$, because otherwise a root of unity of order $p^n$ would be mapped to a lower order root of unity. One of the keys is to see the constraint between $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$, Can you see what it is?

Comment: @Jyrki  Would I be right in saying $\zeta_{p^{n+1}}^p=\zeta_{p^n}$ so $\zeta^{a_n}_{p^n}=g(\zeta_{p^n})=g(\zeta_{p^{n+1}}^p)=g(\zeta_{p^{n+1}})^p=(\zeta_{p^{n+1}}^{a_{n+1}})^p=\zeta_{p^n}^{a_{n+1}}$ and so $a_{n+1}\equiv a_n$ $\text{mod}(p^n)$. So would $(a_n)_n\in \mathbb Z_p$ and since each $a_n$ is coprime to $p$ then it is actually in $\mathbb Z_p^{\times}$? regards

Comment: Yes. I think that's the correct line of reasoning, Pete!

Comment: Many thanks for your hint Jyrki.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: why does $g$ map $\zeta_{p^n}$ to another primitive $p^n$-th root of unity? Is it because an element $g$ in the Galois group restricted to $K_n$ is a $\mathbb Q$-automorphism of $K_n$ so that the orders are preserved? Many thanks

Comment: Correct, @user181834. $K_n$ is Galois over $\Bbb{Q}$, so any automorphism of $K_\infty$ must map the subfield $K_n$ to itself. Or, because as an automorphism $g$ is injective. If $g(\zeta_{p^n})$ were not primitive, we would have $g(\zeta_{p^n})^{p^{n-1}}=1$, So
$$g(1)=1=g(\zeta_{p^n}^{p^{n-1}}),$$ contradicting injectivity of $g$.

Comment: @pete_m Related (not identical, of course): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104004